# how select max(salary) of employee each department with employee_id and emp_name

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to select emp_id,department_id,max(salary) each department but I use group by department_id and it has error ora-00979

3 column is in the same table(employees)

How can I fix it

```
select  department_id, employee_id as "ID",first_name || ' ' || last_name as "Name",max(salary)as "SALARY"
from EMPLOYEES
group by  department_id
order by department_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery with department_id and the max salary and then join to the main table:

```
select 
  e.department_id, 
  t.employee_id as id,
  t.first_name || ' ' || t.last_name as name,
  e.maxsalary 
from (
  select 
    department_id, 
    max(salary) as maxsalary 
  from 
    EMPLOYEES
  group by 
    department_id 
) e
inner join 
  EMPLOYEES t 
on 
  t.department_id = e.department_id and t.salary = e.maxsalary
order by e.department_id;
```

See the [demo](http://tpcg.io/u4ECPS)

**EMPLOYEES**

```
EMPLOYEE_ID DEPARTMENT_ID   SALARY  FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME
    1          1            10000       A           B
    2          1            20000       C           D
    3          1            150000      E           F
    4          2            12000       G           H
    5          2            10000       I           J
    6          3            20000       K           L
    7          4            11000       M           N
    8          4            11000       O           P
    9          4            11000       Q           R
    10         4            10000       S           T
```

**Result**

```
DEPARTMENT_ID   ID  NAME    MAXSALARY
    1            3  E F      150000
    2            4  G H       12000
    3            6  K L       20000
    4            7  M N       11000
    4            8  O P       11000
    4            9  Q R       11000
```

Comment: but all column is in the same table it can't use join table

Comment: Yes you can join a table by itself, although this is not exactly the case here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `keep`:

```
select  department_id,
        max(employee_id) keep (dense_rank first order by salary desc) as "ID",
        max(first_name || ' ' || last_name) keep (dense_rank first order by salary desc, employee_id desc) as "Name", 
        max(salary) as "SALARY"
from employees e
group by  department_id
order by department_id;
```

Comment: thank you very much it can work but i don't know how code work because i just learn sql

Answer (score 0):

The error is because employee_id is not in the group.

A possible solution is:

```
select department_id, ID, Name, SALARY
from (
    select distinct department_id, 
        first_value(employee_id) over (partition by department_id order by salary desc) as ID,
        first_value(first_name || ' ' || last_name) over (partition by department_id order by salary desc) as Name,
        first_value(salary) over (partition by department_id order by salary desc)as SALARY
    from EMPLOYEES
)
order by department_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT department_id, salary AS "Salary", employee_id AS "ID", first_name || ' ' || last_name AS "Name" FROM employees 
WHERE salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees) GROUP BY department_id;
```

I hope it works. :)